# How use just one of an element of two float tuple

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, tuples, break

I am trying to enter by keyboard one of the two types of tuples that contain float numbers as well as the position of each float number of the chosen tuple to then be multiplied by an integer number entered via the keyboard and which will represent the total amount of the position of the float number of the selected tuple. Any idea?

```
 prompt = "\nPlease enter the type of the bonus: "
 prompt2 = "\nEnter the price of the bonus: "
 prompt3 = "\nEenter the quantity of bonus: "
 prompt += "\n(Enter 'quit' when you finished.) "
 bono_basico_1 = (0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05)
 bono_basico_2 = (0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.10)
 bono_basico_1_0 = bono_basico_1[0]
 bono_basico_1_1 = bono_basico_1[1]
 bono_basico_1_2 = bono_basico_1[2]
 bono_basico_1_3 = bono_basico_1[3]
 bono_basico_1_4 = bono_basico_1[4]
 bono_basico_2_0 = bono_basico_2[0]
 bono_basico_2_1 = bono_basico_2[1]
 bono_basico_2_2 = bono_basico_2[2]
 bono_basico_2_3 = bono_basico_2[3]
 bono_basico_2_4 = bono_basico_2[4]
 while True:
     tipo_bono = tuple(input(prompt))
     precio_bono = floatr(input(prompt2))
     cant_bono = int(input(prompt3))
     for tipos_bonos in tipo_bono:
         if tipos_bonos == bono_basico_1 and precio_bono == bono_basico_1_0:
             print(f"El total a pagar por”, {tipos_bonos}, “es:”, {cant_bono * bono_basico_1_0})
         elif tipos_bonos == bono_basico_1 and precio_bono == bono_basico_1_1:
             print(f"El total a pagar por”,{tipos_bonos}, “es:”, {cant_bono * bono_basico_1_1})
         elif tipos_bonos == bono_basico_1 and precio_bono == bono_basico_1_2:
             print(f"El total a pagar por”, {tipos_bonos}, “es :”,  {cant_bono * bono_basico_1_2})
         elif tipos_bonos == bono_basico_1 and precio_bono == bono_basico_1_3:
             print(f"El total a pagar por”, {tipos_bonos}, “es:”, {cant_bono * bono_basico_1_3})
         elif tipos_bonos == bono_basico_1 and precio_bono == bono_basico_1_4:
             print(f"El total a pagar por”, {tipos_bonos}, “es:”, {cant_bono * bono_basico_1_4})
      for mas_tipos_bonos in tipo_bono:
          if mas_tipos_bonos == bono_basico_2 and precio_bono == bono_basico_2_0:
             print(f"El total a pagar por”, {mas_tipos_bonos}, “es:”, {cant_bono * bono_basico_2_0})
          elif mas_tipos_bonos == bono_basico_2 and precio_bono == bono_basico_2_1:
             print(f"El total a pagar por”, {mas_tipos_bonos}, “es:”, {cant_bono * bono_basico_2_1})
          elif mas_tipos_bonos == bono_basico_2 and precio_bono == bono_basico_2_2:
             print(f"El total a pagar por”, {mas_tipos_bonos}, “es:”, {cant_bono * bono_basico_2_2})
          elif mas_tipos_bonos == bono_basico_2 and precio_bono == bono_basico_2_3:
             print(f"El total a pagar por”, {mas_tipos_bonos}, “es:”, {cant_bono * bono_basico_2_3})
          elif mas_tipos_bonos == bono_basico_2 and precio_bono == bono_basico_2_4:
             print(f"El total a pagar por”, {mas_tipos_bonos}, “es:”, {cant_bono * bono_basico_2_4})
          elif mas_tipos_bonos and tipos_bonos == 'quit':
            break
          else:
            print(tipos_bonos)
```

When the tuple that contains the type of bonus is introduced as well as the one that represents the price, it will be multiplied by the whole number and at the end the total to be paid for the amount of bonuses chosen will be obtained until the word quit is written.